# Is there any criteria on which question closure statistics are sorted in 10k tools?

Tags: support, 10k-tools, statistics

On [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com), the closure statistics table seems to be sorted on some criteria. For example, when I saw [statistics for past week](https://askubuntu.com/tools/question-close-stats?daterange=last7days) on Tuesday, the table was:

[image: Question Closure statistics on Tuesday]

But on Saturday, i.e. today, the table is

[image: Question Closure statistics on Saturday]

Looking closely, the "duplicate" statistics are no longer on top and that of "opinion-based" aren't the bottom.

So, is there any criteria of this sorting? Does it change daily?

Comment: It might be that there is no explicit `order by` on the SQL query in which case the sorting is *whatever SQL Server comes up with*. Earlier versions of SQL Server had some basis ground rules so that the order of the rows came out somewhat predictable but with the newer versions that changed so a `select * from posts` could give you a different order of the rows for each run even if the table hasn't changed.

Comment: @rene That actually makes sense. I assume that the results are fetched only once a day since even I refresh the page, the order is unchanged.

Comment: Yeah, I assume it is cached as well.